# problem uploading image from cell phone with php 8.0

Tags: php

I am working with php 8.0 with mvc, I find an error that when I want to take a photo from the cell phone it does not upload the path or save the image on the server, but if I do it from the computer it does upload, without any problem

I have tried several things I have also used the accept = "image / *" capture = "camera"
but it didn't work either

```html
        $ruta = "";

       if(isset($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]) && $_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"] !== ''){
       list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]);

         $nuevoAncho = 500;
          $nuevoAlto = 500;


          $directorio = "vistas/img/usuarios/".$_POST["registroNombre"];

          mkdir($directorio, 0755);



          if($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["type"] == "image/jpeg"){


            $aleatorio = mt_rand(100,999);

            $ruta = "vistas/img/usuarios/".$_POST["registroNombre"]."/".$aleatorio.".jpg";

            $origen = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]);            

            $destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto);

            imagecopyresized($destino, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto, $ancho, $alto);

            imagejpeg($destino, $ruta);

          }

          if($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["type"] == "image/png"){

       

            $aleatorio = mt_rand(100,999);

            $ruta = "vistas/img/usuarios/".$_POST["registroNombre"]."/".$aleatorio.".png";

            $origen = imagecreatefrompng($_FILES["nuevaFoto"]["tmp_name"]);           

            $destino = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto);

            imagecopyresized($destino, $origen, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevoAncho, $nuevoAlto, $ancho, $alto);

            imagepng($destino, $ruta);

          }

        }
```

Comment: yeah --  <div class="form-group">
          
        

          <input type="file" class="nuevaFoto" name="nuevaFoto" accept="image/*" capture="camera"  required>

          <p class="help-block">Tomar Foto por favor</p>
<div class="text-center">

Comment: Start debugging with a var_dump of $_FILES.